# R restarting during joining of multiple dataframes using full_joins

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr

I'm trying to join over 20 dataframes using `full_join` function by two identifiers (chr).
The issue is Rstudio restarting before the completion of the process. Kindly let me know how to overcome the issue. However, This code is working well with 4-5 dataframes.

`dg_list` contains the list of dataframes.

header of each dataframe is

```
 chr      start      end  StoZ Tier  Gene     cohort         
<chr>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <chr>
```

I'm using the following code and chr and Gene as identifier,

```
AllCohortGene<- dg_list %>% reduce(full_join, by=c("chr", "Gene"))
```

My R Version is 4.2.2 .

Comment: By "restart" do you mean "crash"?  Are there any errors or warning messages? Is the issue unique to RStudio - does the code run okay if you run the code in the built-in R Gui or use the command line instead of RStudio? Does it seem memory-related - does it work if you run it on only 10 or only 5 data frames? Is there one particular data frame that causes the issue? How big are these data frames?

Comment: To, @GregorThomas , No there is no warning msg. 4-5 dataframes are merging well with this code. Exactly I don't know any particular df is causing this issue or not. The dataframes are not so big, as every df has 7 cols and 1 to 3500 rows. Even I successfully used the same code for a much larger df (around half a million rows).

Comment: Well, if 4-5 data frames work, do 10 data frames work? Do 15? See if you can find the first data frame number that doesn't work, and then try running the code on `dg_list[c(1, first_data_that_doesnt_work)]` to see if the problem is that data frame.

Comment: And since it sounds like you haven't tried the code on the command line or the R Gui, I'll assume the issue is r-related by not RStudio-related and edit your question and tags accordingly.

Comment: Even though each data.frame may be small, doing `full_join`s can quickly balloon the number of records, and you may be running out of RAM. What if you do e.g. `inner_join`s instead?

Comment: Further, I tried it using the terminal and both inner_join and full_join show the same ERROR, Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.4 Gb.

Comment: It sounds like `chr` + `Gene` are not unique keys for at least some of your tables, so each join to these tables multiplies the size of your table by some value >1, and at some point the table you're asking for is larger than your computer's memory can hold. That isn't really an R issue as much as a database issue about understanding your tables and how they should relate to each other.

Comment: Thank you very much @JonSpring for bringing to light the underlying cause of this issue. I added another identifier and it works.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jon Spring said, the fundamental cause for this issue is that `chr` and `Gene` may not work as a unique key. As a result, I added another identifier `start`, and it now works well.

```
  AllCohortGene<- dg_list %>% reduce(full_join, by=c("chr", "start", "Gene"))
```

Thanks, everyone for providing valuable suggestions.